# Converting unsigned char array to an integer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, int

As far as I know, in C programming language, an array is stored on the memory element by element. (i.e., element 0, element 1, element 2, ... , element n). I'm trying to see that with the following code:

```
unsigned char a[] = { '\1' , '\2', '\3' ,'\4' };  
printf("%d\n", (int*) a);
```

Since unsigned char is 1 byte and an integer is 4 bytes; I thought it has to print the value:

> 00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 = 2^2 + 2^8 + 2^9 + 2^17 + 2^24 = 16909060

However, when I run this program, it generates different results for every trials.

What am I missing here?

Comment: On most computers, the byte order will be opposite from what you assumed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29969049/694576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `*(int *)a`, otherwise you're just printing an address.

However, this will invoke implementation-defined behaviour:

- You will get a different result depending on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform.
- Depending on the platform, the `char` array may not be properly aligned to be read as an `int`.
- The compiler may perform funky optimizations based on assumptions that you will never read the `char` array through an `int *` - you are breaking what are known as the *strict aliasing* rules.

Comment: Also, what it prints depends on the endian-ness on this box.

Comment: Re "You will get one of two different results depending on endianness." Not just two. There are still some mixed endian boxes around. E.g., 0x2143 or 0x3412.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes. Thanks. It worked great. And the endianness of my platform (visual studio) was: 00000100 00000011 00000010 00000001. I think it is called "little endian".

Comment: Is it possible do this conversion with a implementation-independent approach? maybe writing a function which iterate over each bit of the unsigned char array and return a `long int´ type?