# Insert array of hex codes into an integer

Tags: arrays, c, insert, endianness

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be pretty basic but either I'm just ignoring something obvious or it is actually a bit tricky. My problem is: I have an array of 4 chars that contains 4 hex values. For example:

```
array[0] = 0xD8
array[1] = 0xEC
array[2] = 0xA2 
array[3] = 0x83
```

I want to store this array in an integer with the combined value, in this case 0xD8ECA283

I've tried doing logical OR and then shifting the bits and with this method I managed to store the value of 0xD8 in the integer, but not the rest. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Why not just work with the array as if it were a pointer to an integer? E.g. `int integer = *((int*)array)`.

Comment: @Witiko Because of [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @Witiko That may not work due to endianness issues. The value you get will be different depending on whether it's a big-endian or little-endian plaform

Comment: @Witiko: Also you might face alignment issues.

Comment: @Witiko on top of endianness and alignment issues, it violates strict aliasing

Comment: @ali: What kind of alignment issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int i;
int combined = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    combined = (combined << 8) | ((unsigned char) array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is actually pretty close to what I was trying so at least I was at the right track. Should have kept at it longer. Anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

Use the binary OR operator, and an integer whose precision is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, which is the type `unsigned long` (although the type `uint_least32_t` could also be used).

Unsigned integer is used so any potential undefined and/or implementation defined behavior that is present when shifting signed integers is avoided.

This solution is independent of endianness.

```
unsigned long a = ( ( ( unsigned long )array[0] & 0xFF ) << 24 ) |
                  ( ( ( unsigned long )array[1] & 0xFF ) << 16 ) |
                  ( ( ( unsigned long )array[2] & 0xFF ) << 8 ) |
                  ( ( ( unsigned long )array[3] & 0xFF ) << 0 ) ;
```

Casts to `( unsigned long )` are made to avoid intermediate implicit conversion to `int`.
The `& 0xFF` operation is there to remove unnecessary bits (if there were any in an unlikely scenario where CHAR_BIT != 8).

Comment: @DrKoch Yes, it was intentional for consistency and readability.

Comment: This solved my problem, but I accepted another answer because I thought it was a bit easier to read. But thanks anyway