# How to convert u8 array to u32?

Tags: c, arrays, int, hex

How to convert u8 array to u32?

For example:

```
u8 a[4];
u32 b; 

a[0] = 0x00;
a[1] = 0x00;
a[2] = 0x00;
a[3] = 0x09;
```

How to convert the array a (8bitx4=32bit) to b(32bit)?

Comment: Which 32 bit number would you expect your example code to return?

Comment: unsigned 32 bit @Wormbo

Comment: I mean the exact value. 0x00000009, 0x09000000 or whatever else you might have had in mind.

Comment: 0x00000009 @Wormbo

Comment: Okay, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969049/insert-array-of-hex-codes-into-an-integer

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned char a[4];
unsigned int b;

a[0] = 0x00;
a[1] = 0x00;
a[2] = 0x00;
a[3] = 0x09;

int n = 1;
if (*(char *)&n == 1) {
    std::reverse(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
}

b = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&a);
```